# Disable virtual keyboard on readonly input by JavaScript on WinPhone

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard, virtual, readonly

I have an input with readonly attribute, I cannot it set to disabled because it should be ability to select and copy value. When I set focus on input I see cursor (on WinPhone and IE) and virtual keyboard appears. How desable at least the virtual keyboad?

Comment: If the keyboard appears on a readonly `<input>` I'd say that's just a platform/browser bug.

Comment: make it a label instead of a readonly input?